# Check in which interval lies all values in vector R

Tags: r, vector

suppose I have a vector of size 915. Name of the vector is `base`

```
[1] 1.467352 4.651796 4.949438 5.625817 5.691591 5.839439 5.927564 7.152487 8.195661 8.640770....591.3779 591.9426 592.0126 592.3861 593.2927 593.3991 593.6104 594.1526 594.5325 594.7093
```

Also I have constructed another vector: 
`intervals <- c(0,seq(from = 1, by = 6,length.out = 100))` we can interpret this vector as intervals.

Then I want to test in which interval(vector `interval`) lies each value of vector `base`. For example first element of `base` lies in second interval( `1.467352` doesn't lie into interval `(0,1]`, but lies into `(1,7]`). The same procedure I want to execute for each value in `base`

From this I want to create third vector, which means the number of interval in which lies i-th element of `base`

BUT! The maximum size of each interval is, for example, 5(One interval can consist only five elements). It means, that even if seven elements of vector `base` lies in the second interval, this second interval **must** include only five.

```
third_vector = 2,2,2,2,2,3,3....
```

As we see, only five elements are in the second interval. 6-th and 7-th element due to the lack of space must lie into the third interval.

And the question is: how can I effectively implement this in R?

Comment: You can use  `cut` to test the belonging of array elements to intervals. I don't however understand what the last "passage" should do (to be clear: the one after "BUT") .

Comment: @LorenzoBusetto for example we figured out, that first five elements of vector base lie in the second interval. In our case it means, that second interval is full(because it can contain maximum 5 elements). That's why we should shift 6-th and 7-th element from the second interval to the third one.

Comment: But then the limits of your intervals will change... If you just want 5 elements for each interval, then you can just sort the vector and divide it in groups of five...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to bin the data into quantiles, where the number of quantiles is set based on the maximum number of values allowed in a given interval. Below is an example. Let me know if this is what you had in mind:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(83, 10, 5))

# Cut into intervals containing no more than n values
n = 5
dat$x.bin = cut(dat$x, quantile(dat$x, seq(0,1,length=ceiling(nrow(dat)/n)+1)), 
                include.lowest=TRUE)

# Check
table(dat$x.bin)
```

> ```
> [-1.07,3.62]  (3.62,5.87]   (5.87,6.7]   (6.7,7.29]   (7.29,8.2]   (8.2,9.32]  (9.32,9.72] 
>            5            5            5            5            5            4            5 
>  (9.72,9.97]  (9.97,10.8]  (10.8,11.7]  (11.7,12.1]  (12.1,12.9]  (12.9,13.5]    (13.5,14] 
>            5            5            5            5            4            5            5 
>    (14,15.5]  (15.5,17.4]    (17.4,22] 
>            5            5            5
> ```

To implement @LorenzoBusetto's suggestion, you could do the following. This method ensures that every interval except the last contains `n` values:

```
dat = dat[order(dat$x),]
dat$x.bin = 0:(nrow(dat)-1) %/% n
```